# How to use LIKE %a% when passing a parameter in raw sql django

Tags: sql, django, rawsql

I have a parameter search_query and I want to get all the objects that consist search_query using only raw sql(I know that Django has built-in functions for that)
Here is my code:

```
def search(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT (Lastname + ' ' + Firstname + ' ' + Patronymic) as n from Person")
    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    search_query = request.GET.get('search','')

    cursor.execute("SELECT (Lastname + ' ' + Firstname + ' ' + Patronymic) as n from Person WHERE Lastname LIKE %s",[search_query])
    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return render(request,'other.html',{'data':data,'search_q':search_query})
```

Tried to do like this `WHERE Lastname LIKE %%s%`, but it didn't work. Couldn't find anything in the internet((

Comment: `WHERE Lastname LIKE %%%s%%`